# Rand with chance item Table start from lower chance to higher

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get one item from a table starting from lower chance to higher
when `like chance = 100` and `chance = 100` then return only one item:

```
$table = [itemid=23,chance=55],[itemid=55,chance=100],[itemid66,chance=100],[itemid=5,chance=1]
rand($table[0]-1,$table[1]-2);
```

Comment: nice name ;) .....